# Angular 6, I get the following error - getForecast is not a function

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular. I am making a weather app. Keep getting an error: `getForecast is not a function`, I've been trying to fix but cannot seem to get to the bottom of it.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

I have a jsfiddle with the local-forecast.component files html + ts

Not sure if its a problem outside of these, I can give more details if required.

http://jsfiddle.net/anxsr4d6/

HTML snippet

```
<button (click)="getForecast()">Get Forecast</button>
```

TS File snippet

```
getForecast() {
    this.forecast = this.weather.currentForecast(this.lat, this.lng)
    .pipe(tap(data => console.log(data)),)
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mf-wx-app-1

Comment: it appears your jsfiddle isn't set up for an Angular application; it's compiling typescript to pure vanilla JS. to my knowloedge, JSfiddle doesn't support compiling an Angular app. Could you try posting your code in a Stackblitz? Stackblitz supports compiling and serving an Angular application.

Comment: I threw your code into a StackBlitz and mocked up a weather service: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d3wanb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts.  It seems that everything works well enough there.  Maybe something in your outer setup?

Comment: Thanks for doing that. I Will investigate further. I will also try and add my setup to the StackBlitz to see the outer setup

Comment: I have put a new SB up as still getting the error & not sure why. Thanks https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mf-wx-app-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue in the end with external help.
Heres the fix, if it helps others.

I was calling forecast.html file twice (app controller and forecast controller).

Assuming you don't have any router, simply call your  tag inside your app.component.html :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mf-wx-app-1-zwabvb

*Edited app.component.tsn app.component.html, and app.module.ts (added httpservice in the imports array)* (edited)